# How can I modify original variable when changing variable in List? C#

Tags: c#, list, pointers, variables

Let's say I have this code (this is an example):

```
int test = 5;
List<int> testlist = new List<int>();
testlist.Add(test);
test = 7;
Console.WriteLine(testlist[0]);
```

This gives output: 5. What I want is 7.

How can I make it so that element in list is the same as the original one? In other words I want it to also change element in list when I change the original value and the other way around. In C++ I would make a Vector of pointers. AFAIK there are no pointer types in C# so what is the workaround?

Comment: [Value types vs Reference types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: Recent version of C# incorporated `ref` variables, which are similar to pointers. That or store a list of objects whose properties you change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you're storing ints, wich are value types. What you can do, is create a wrapper class that has one public int. Instead of making a list of ints, you make a list of your wrapper class. That way when you change the value of the int, the changes will show in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
        int test = 5;
        List<int> testlist = new List<int>();
        test = 7; // this line need to come up
        testlist.Add(test); // This line comes after test = 7;
        Console.WriteLine(testlist[0]);
```

Now you can get output 7.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, these are still separate values in memory. What if I want to change testlist[0] and read new value from test variable? I want it to work so that I can change the values multiple times and each time, no matter which one I access, it gives me the value that I changed to.